# out of memory error action bar

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-titlebar

My app throws out of memory error when I am trying to include action bar in order to setup a title to activities. Unfortunately, these activities contain images to display.How do I overcome this to add title to activities while displaying images in same activity. I have taken care of all other things in Manifest and activity.xml to display title.Below is the code.

```
 public class ScanActivity extends Activity{

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

    ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Preview");
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

here is the error:

```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1627)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setIcon(ActionBarView.java:1037)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setDefaultIcon(PhoneWindow.java:1550)
        at android.app.Activity.initActionBar(Activity.java:2017)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2032)
        at com.example.kittu.ClientLync.ScanActivity.onCreate(ScanActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you need to scale your images to the screen size. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: same issue on activities that donot display any images as well.Any suggestion for this pls.